# What happens if clan leaders abuse their power?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of Clans, people in a clan can be promoted to different ranks which give the player authority. But how can a player be punished if they abuse their power, though? People who are of lower rank than him/her can't do anything.

I once joined a clan where I saw angry messages in the chat because the newly-promoted leader kicked people out to troll and be "funny." Since the leader has the most power, the rest of the clan members (including me) couldn't do anything about it. How would Supercell punish people who abuse their authoritative power in clans?

Comment: If others agree with you, get out of his clan and leave him alone. There are many more clans available out there or you can create one of your own with serious people.

Comment: You can do something. Leave. Talk to the other members and set up another Clan without him.

Comment: I can say from experience that the worst punishment for a clan leader is a bunch of clan mates leaving.  Recruiting is a grueling task, as many new recruits you get will simply ask for expensive troops, get them, and leave.  Once a clan falls below a certain critical mass it becomes hard to recruit more quality players and eventually you even lose that ability to war.  If you donate, and regularly play, there are thousands of clans out there that would jump at the chance to get you.  Leave that pesky leader and don't look back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clans in Clash of Clans are considered to be property of the leader. With that said, a leader can invite or expell anyone who he pleases, and that does not break the rules.

The only exception is when inviting and expelling breaks war rules (by exploiting a loophole of sorts).

Other than that there is no reason to report a clan leader, unless he is cheating (or exploiting the system) or alternatively being verbally abusive.

If any other member abuses it's up to the leader to decide what to do with him.

Comment: You can just all quit en-mass.  He can have this clan to himself.

Answer (score 8):

They wouldn't punish them at all. Especially if it was the leader, as it is their clan, so they can run it how they wish, and people are free to join which ever clan will let them, and can leave anytime they wish. If a leader is kicking people to be funny though, I would imagine that people would leave his clan pretty quickly, and soon he wouldn't have any members to kick.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do anything.

Vote with your feet - find another clan.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to report it beacause supercell cant go though every clan chat. I have been in clans where this has happend so I know how frustrating this can be. Take a screenshot and send it to supercell support and they will investigate.

Comment: Supercell won't and can't interfere with clans